# Directive not working with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I have the following directive that works correctly unless i use a ng-if on the containing element as well. What I am trying to do is simply set a dynamic property on the scope with an associated function. The scope does not contain the property (undefined).

any help would be great!

```
app.directive('stRefresh', function () {
    return {
        require: '^stTable',
        link: function (scope, ele, attr, ctrl) {
            if (attr.stRefresh) {
                var name = attr.stRefresh;
                scope[name] = scope[name] || {};
                scope[name].refresh = function () {
                    return ctrl.search();
                };
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening that is incorrect

Comment: the scope does not contain the property (undefined)

Comment: any particular reason you are using ng-if for this, ng-show is faster overall and would likely resolve the issue

Comment: Yes there is a particular reason I do not want the element added to the DOM.

Comment: If your error is "scope does not contain the property (undefined)" that implies that the `name` variable is undefined. Have you tried stepping through this with the debugger or adding some logging? Edit: after thinking about it, I suspect the undefined error is coming from the controller code due to the problem described in my answer. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what doesn't work, but I suspect that you have been bitten by [the problem of nested scopes](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html).

The `ng-if` directive creates a child scope. When you modify the scope in your directive:

```
scope[name] = scope[name] || {};
```

You are modifying the child scope. Due to prototypal inheritance, this does not modify the scope of the parent. Therefore, if you are expecting to see a change in the parent scope, you won't see it.

To fix it, you need to add a dot to the scope reference. Something like this:

```
scope.data[name] = scope.data[name] || {};
scope.data[name].refresh = function () {
    return ctrl.search();
};
```

The `scope.data` property needs to be a reference to an object. Since you are not modifying the reference, you can modify the properties of that object from both parent and child scopes.